# creating circles in python to mask an image and count pixels within each circle

Tags: python, image, image-processing

In python, I am trying to separate an image into circles and calculate the number of black pixels in each circle.

For example, I have an image captured with a fisheye lens (a hemispherical image) (drawn example below) and I want to divide the image into small circles capturing part of the image from a small circle in the middle to the whole of the image. 
 [image: picture of a captured image]

I would like to split the image into x number of circles capturing part of the image each time (see images below)
[image: circle 1]
[image: circle 2]

Once I have the circle images I can calculate the number of pixels in each image.

I tried:
    `Image=Image.new("RGB", (2000,2000))
      draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
      draw.ellipse((20,20,1800,1800),fill(255,255,255)`

Then created a mask from this, however regardless of how I change the numbers int the draw.ellipse the circle only ever captures the whole of the image but makes the image itself smaller.

Any ideas or recommendations on how to fix this would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at OpenCV for such tasks. You can transform the circle to whole contour and calculate the radius of the circle. Then you can draw circle and draw them on a mask and perform `cv2.bitwise_and` to make the circle ROI over the image. You can iterate and multply with an integer of your choice (in my case 10) the radius of the ROI circle. Hope it helps. Cheers!

Example code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('circle.png')
h, w = img.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = np.ones((10,10),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel, iterations = 2)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(opening,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
extLeft = tuple(cnt[cnt[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
extRight = tuple(cnt[cnt[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
radius = (extRight[0] - extLeft[0])/2
print(extRight[0], extLeft[0])
print(radius)

M = cv2.moments(cnt)
cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
print(cx, cy)

for i in range(1,30):
    if i*10<radius:
        print(i*10)
        cv2.circle(mask,(cx,cy), i*10, 255, -1)
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
        pixels = np.sum(res == 255)
        cv2.putText(res,'Pixel count: '+str(pixels),(30,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow('img', res)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    else:
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=opening)
        pixels = np.sum(res == 255)
        cv2.putText(img,'Pixel count: '+str(pixels),(30,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow('img', res)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

Try with a different way to calculate the middle

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('circle.png')
h, w = img.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = np.ones((10,10),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel, iterations = 2)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(opening,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
cv2.imshow('img22', opening)
extLeft = tuple(cnt[cnt[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
extRight = tuple(cnt[cnt[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
radius = (extRight[0] - extLeft[0])/2

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

cx = int(x+(w/2))
cy = int(y+h/2)

for i in range(1,30):
    if i*10<radius:
        print(i*10)
        cv2.circle(mask,(cx,cy), i*10, 255, -1)
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
        pixels = np.sum(res == 255)
        cv2.putText(res,'Pixel count: '+str(pixels),(30,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow('img', res)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    else:
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=opening)
        pixels = np.sum(res == 255)
        cv2.putText(img,'Pixel count: '+str(pixels),(30,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow('img', res)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Edit 2:

Okay so my assumption from your first example image was that your image will be almost a circle from the get go. Because it is not you have to calculate the center differently (like from my first edit - from bounding box) and make a bigger kernel (40,40) - due to the fact that the image is very large. Plus you have to make for i in range threshold (like 10000). This will work:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('circleroi.jpg')
h, w = img.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = np.ones((40,40),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel, iterations = 2)

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(opening,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
extLeft = tuple(cnt[cnt[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
extRight = tuple(cnt[cnt[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
radius = (extRight[0] - extLeft[0])/2

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

cx = int(x+(w/2))
cy = int(y+h/2)

for i in range(1,10000):
    if i*10<radius:
        cv2.circle(mask,(cx,cy), i*10, 255, -1)
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
        pixels = np.sum(res == 255)
        cv2.putText(res,'Pixel count: '+str(pixels),(30,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow('img', res)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    else:
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=opening)
        pixels = np.sum(res == 255)
        cv2.putText(img,'Pixel count: '+str(pixels),(30,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow('img', res)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, it seems great and I have tried this but unfortunately the image is really big and the circle does not appear in the middle of the screen. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Can you post the this picture? Try to make a bigger kernel for the opening (20,20 or 30,30) - maybe it does not make one contour if the kernel size is too small hence the different middle point

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have added the image to the question above as I was not sure how to add the image into the comments section. Making the kernel bigger didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Want I meant was if you could add the original "big" image without any processing

Comment: hi, thank you for the help. I have uploaded the test image that i am running code on but the problem of the small circle not in the middle of the image is still happening.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly straightforward to do in pure numpy if you're familiar enough with the library:

```
# Create some fake data
np.random.seed(100)
fake_im_arr = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(2000,2000))

# Function definition for creating masks
def create_circle_mask(X_arr, Y_arr, center, radius):
    c_x, c_y = center
    dists_sqrd = (X_arr - c_x)**2 + (Y_arr - c_y)**2
    return dists_sqrd <= radius**2

# Using the two together:
center, radius = (1000, 1000), 5
size_x, size_y = fake_im_arr.shape
mask = create_circle_mask(*np.ogrid[0:size_x, 0:size_y], center=center, radius=radius)
n_black_in_circle = ((fake_im_arr == 1) & mask).sum() # This is your answer (39 in this case)
```

To see what the various arrays look like:

```
fake_im_arr[center[0] - radius:center[0] + (radius + 1),
            center[1] - radius:center[1] + (radius + 1)]

array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

mask[center[0] - radius:center[0] + (radius + 1),
     center[1] - radius:center[1] + (radius + 1)].astype('int')

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

np.where(mask, fake_im_arr, 0)[center[0] - radius:center[0] + (radius + 1),
                               center[1] - radius:center[1] + (radius + 1)]

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```